# python-django не работает прокрутка в Carousel

Tags: python, django

Не работает Carousel. Может кто помочь. Django только начал учить
models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from datetime import datetime


class News(models.Model):
    news_title = models.CharField('название статьи', max_length=200)
    news_short_text = models.CharField('короткий текст статьи', max_length=400)
    news_text = models.TextField('текст статьи')
    news_pub_date = models.DateField('дата публикации')
    video = models.FileField(upload_to='media/', null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.news_title

    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.news_pub_date >= (timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=7))


class Image(models.Model):
    news = models.ForeignKey(News, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name="news_post")
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="media/", verbose_name='Изображение')
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import Http404
from .models import News
from django.core.paginator import Paginator

def index(request):
    latest_news_list = News.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    return render(request, 'news/list.html', {'latest_news_list': latest_news_list})


def news(request):
    latest_news = News.objects.order_by('-news_pub_date')[:]
    paginator = Paginator(latest_news, 6)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    latest_news = paginator.get_page(page)
    return render(request, 'news/news.html', {'latest_news': latest_news})


def contacs(request):
    return render(request, 'news/contacs.html', {})


def detail(request, news_id):
    try:
        a = News.objects.get(id=news_id)
    except:
        raise Http404("СТАТЬЯ НЕ НАЙДЕНА")
    latest_news_list = a.news_post.order_by('-id').all()
    return render(request, 'news/detail.html', {'news': a, 'latest_news_list': latest_news_list})
```

detail.html

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}{{news.news_title}}{%endblock%}
{% block content%}
<center>
<div class="grid-container">
<h1 >  {{news.news_title}} </h1>
 <p>{{news.news_text}}</p>
  {% if news.video %}
 <h2>
<video  autoplay preload="metadata" width=100% height=100%>
<source src="{{news.video.url}}" type="video/mp4">
<source src="{{news.video.url}}" type="video/wbm">
</video>
 </h2>
  {% endif %}

{{article.news_text}}
 <em text-align="right">  {{news.news_pub_date}} </em>
<hr>

<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
       {% for news in latest_news_list %}
       <div class="item {% if forloop.first %} active{% endif %}">
          <img class="first-slide" src="{{news.image.url}}" alt="First slide">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
            {% endfor %}
      </div>
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div><!-- /.carousel -->



</div>
</center>
{% endblock %}
```